# How do you turn on boost in Just Cause 2 Multiplayer?

Tags: just-cause-2-multiplayer

A friend of mine made a server and we want to enable boost. How can we do that?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to get [Boost-lite](https://github.com/jc2mp/boost_lite) for your server and install it under the scripts directory, or you can script one yourself. You can then enable it using `load Boost-lite` in the server console.

Comment: ...and you enable it by holding shift. It works in cars and boats but not planes or choppers.